# i need an example of fixed px size and making the box different sizes

Tags: html, css, input, label

can anyone please give me an example of fixed px size and what is the use of it.

and also can u please help me wrapping those input and labels inside a div element and making the box different sizes

```
            <label for="Year">Year :</label>
            <input type="text" id="Year" name="year" placeholder="(YYYY)">

            <label for="LicencePlate">Licence Plate:</label>
            <input type="text" id="LicencePlate" name="licencePlate" placeholder="LicencePlate">

            <label for="DateBooked">Date Booked:</label>
            <input type="text" id="DateBooked" name="dateBooked" placeholder="24/10/2017">

            <label for="TimeBooked">Time Booked:</label>
            <input type="text" id="TimeBooked" name="timeBooked" placeholder="14:00">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#container .subcontainer .label{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px
}
#container .subcontainer .input{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
}
#container .subcontainer{
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
            <div id='container'>
              <div class='subcontainer'>
                <div class='label'><label for="Year">Year :</label></div>
                <div class='input'><input type="text" id="Year" name="year" placeholder="(YYYY)"></div>
              </div>
              
              <div class='subcontainer'>
                <div class='label'><label for="LicencePlate">Licence Plate:</label></div>
                <div class='input'><input type="text" id="LicencePlate" name="licencePlate" placeholder="LicencePlate"></div>
              </div>
              
              <div class='subcontainer'>
                <div class='label'><label for="DateBooked">Date Booked:</label>
            </div>
                <div class='input'><input type="text" id="DateBooked" name="dateBooked" placeholder="24/10/2017"></div>
              </div>
              
              <div class='subcontainer'>
                <div class='label'><label for="Year">Year :</label></div>
                <div class='input'><input type="text" id="Year" name="year" placeholder="(YYYY)"></div>
              </div>
              
              <div class='subcontainer'>
                <div class='label'><label for="TimeBooked">Time Booked:</label>
            </div>
                <div class='input'><input type="text" id="TimeBooked" name="timeBooked" placeholder="14:00"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I hope above code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone please give me an example of fixed px size

Here is a box with a described size.

```
element {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

> and what is the use of it.

To tell the browser how to display the element

> and also can u please help me wrapping those input and labels inside a div element and making the box different sizes

An example of how you should markup and style lists of input fields

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/at2m1r6v/